# Notepad++: Find & replace with regular expressions

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a file full of lines like this:

```
<td>123.456</td>
```

that I want to convert to:

```
<td class="num">123.456</td>
```

I tried using the advanced find/replace (with regular expressions enabled):

```
find: <td>([0-9\.]+)</td>
replace: <td class="num">\1</td>
```

I can find my td elements fine, but somehow replace gets me an empty TD:

```
<td class="num"></td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me...

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug with Notepad++ or one if its plugins.

Switching the language from HTML to normal text fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Notepad++ myself all that much, but you might check to make sure \1 is the correct... syntax? to use. For example, Dreamweaver uses %1 instead.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't look like a bug to me. I know this post is a few months old, but humor me.

In your find line:
find: ([0-9.]+)

It looks like you only told the engine to find one numeral before the period repeated one or more times. Shouldn't your regex look more like this.

find: ([0-9]+.[0-9]+)

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. :-) `([0-9.]+)` matches 1 or more decimals or periods. Thus, it matches `049.0234.493` and `3059` and `....` What you described sounds like `([0-9]+\.)+`